# Custom gridview in a DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-gridview, baseadapter, android-dialogfragment

I tried to insert a custom gridview into a DialogFragment, and I encountered a problem with setting the adapter to the gridview. After hours of research, I gave up and came here for 
any ideas on what is the problem with the gridview.setAdapter?
Thanks in advance!

The DialogFragment :

```
public class theDialog extends DialogFragment {

private String[] nums ={"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16"};
GridView gridview;
GridAdapter adapter = new GridAdapter(getActivity(),nums);

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid,null);
    gridview = (GridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(adapter); //PROBLEM HERE************

    builder.setView(view);


    Dialog dialog = builder.create();
    return dialog;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you received any errors running your code, you should edit the output of logcat in your question.

To resolve your problem, you should use `view` which you have inflated instead of `getActivity` to find the `gridview`.

The fixed DialogFragment :

```
public class theDialog extends DialogFragment {

private String[] nums ={"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16"};
GridView gridview;
GridAdapter adapter = new GridAdapter(getActivity(),nums);

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid,null);
    // replace getActivity() with view
    gridview = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(adapter); //PROBLEM HERE************

    builder.setView(view);


    Dialog dialog = builder.create();
    return dialog;
}
}
```